# Network setup with Netplan and bridges

Tags: server, 18.04, network-bridge, netplan

I'm having an issue where any bridge I create with netplan doesn't get an address.
The following starts my NIC and I get a DHCP address:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
     enp0s3:
        addresses: []
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
```

This will start a bridge, and it will show up in "ip a" but won't retrieve an IP address from my DHCP server:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
     enp0s3:
        addresses: []
        dhcp4: false
        optional: true
  bridges:
     br0:
       interfaces: [enp0s3]
       dhcp4: true
       optional: true
```

I feel like either I'm missing something really simple here, or this whole Netplan thing was/is terrible.

Comment: Are you trying this in virtual box... ? Having the same issues with a static IP address assigned to the bridge. You will find you can get to it from the console, but not externally. (ssh) etc. I think there is a bug in that the physical interface is not actually routing.

Comment: Yes, in VirtualBox. I'm seeing a few other reports of VBox issues with bridges as well, so maybe this is the culprit.